# Spawn targets at a random position but not blocked by objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using this script in my FPS to spawn enemies at a random position (every 5 seconds), but always within the camera view:

```
Vector3 screenPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Random.Range(0,Screen.width), Random.Range(0,Screen.height), Camera.main.farClipPlane/2));
```

Of course, the floor where my character stands on, blocks the view a bit. With the code above, the enemy can spawn beneath the floor because technically it's within the camera view, but the floor blocks it.

Also, there are houses in my game environment. With the code above, enemies can spawn behind a house so the character can't see them.

I'm looking for a way to resolve both issues. They can both be resolved if I could add this to my script: "an enemy must always spawn in the camera view AND cannot be blocked by other objects".

Any idea how I could change my script to address this issue?

I was thinking of a way to detect whether or not an object is blocked, and if it is, make it respawn. But I'm afraid this will affect the time the spawning occurs (which should always be 5 seconds, even if it has to recalculate a couple of times because the enemy was blocked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Raycast!](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) When you have a spawn point workout the distance from the player to the spawn using [`Vector3.Distance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) once you have that raycast from the player to the spawn location. If the [raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) collides pick a new spawn point since there must be something in the way (and therefore outside of view).

You could pre calculate this a few frames in advance so that you are always spawning a new enemy every 5 seconds. You could even multithread this by shoving the code into a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html).